# Is there any way to reduce margins more quickly when working with media queries?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Look, I have some ready-made landing and now I'm adapting it for tablets, phones and other devices.

I noticed that it is often necessary to adjust Padding and margins for many elements and therefore have to access each element, which is very labor-intensive.

Below I attach a sample code that I sketched

```css
/*Reset style*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 :focus,
 :active {
  outline: none;
}

a:focus,
a:active {
  outline: none;
}

nav,
footer,
header,
aside {
  display: block;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

input,
button,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}

input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
}


/*--------------------*/

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
}

.header__container {}

.header__content {
  background-color: coral;
}

.main__container {
  background-color: darkcyan;
}

.main__hi {
  margin: 50px 70px;
}

.main__features {
  margin: 20px 40px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

.features__img {
  margin: 15px 140px;
  background-color: brown;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_stack.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Header -->
      <div class="header__container">
        <div class="header__content">
          This is header
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main__container">
        <div class="main__hi">
          This is the welcome block of the main container
        </div>
        <div class="main__features">
          This is block with features
          <div class="features__img"> This is img of features</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**So, the question is**: is it possible to configure margin and padding using a short entry, rather than referring to each element? Perhaps this can be done using sass, less or stylus preprocessors?

Comment: You should not be adjusting padding/margin based on screen size, you should be adjusting layout. Have a basic layout that works on the smallest screen width you want to support, get it looking great, don't even think about wider screens at this stage. Then add in major layout styles for wider screens with min-width media queries

Answer (score 0):

How about working with CSS variables? It's supported by default by CSS so using a css preprocessor isn't required.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp

```css
:root {
    --paddingSections: 50px;
    --paddingHeadings: 5px; 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  :root {
    --paddingSections: 100px;
    --paddingHeadings: 25px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  :root {
    --paddingSections: 150px;
    --paddingHeadings: 50px;
  }
}


section {
  background-color: green;
  padding: var(--paddingSections);
}

h1{
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: var(--paddingHeadings);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Resize the screen for different paddings</h1>
</section>
```